# OK to manually rebase feature branches when using Git Flow?

Tags: git-flow

Im using Git Flow: 
http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

Is it OK to manually rebase develop into my feature branches? Other peoples work on develop may affect what im doing so id like to keep my feature branches up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK to rebase the develop branch in a feature branch you are working on.

I do it sometimes when I'm working on a feature that takes a while to develop and in the mean time new features are introduced in the develop branch.